# IE wrong vertical element position

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have website `www.stanosimkovic.sk` and i have problem with vertical positioning right element with text on main page in IE browser. In another browsers it load correctly. Can somebody help me how to fix this issue.

I think problem is somewhere in CSS

```
.alignMiddle {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

But dont know how resolve it, because in Chrome Opera etc. its OK.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+IE+transform+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Also [something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the version of IE, the transform property might not work. So what you have to do is add the [vendors prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). So it should look like this (-ms- is for IE) :

```
.alignMiddle {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

Hope it helps !